# array_walk_recursive to apply function to each array element not working at all

Tags: php

I have the following code on a form page:

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'sanitize');
```

It is used so I can echo the $_POST variables inside of each form field after a user submits a form.

Here is the `sanitize` function:

```
function sanitize ($v) {
    return htmlspecialchars(trim($v), ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

It is not working whatsoever. The $_POST array still contains harmful quotation marks that breaks form elements on the page when I enter something like '"> break' for the value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `array_map`?

Comment: Post your array structure

Answer (score 2):

`array_walk_recursive` returns a boolean. Your function should not be returning the santized output but simply manipulating the input. Also, you may need to declare the input as a reference.

Try this change to the `sanitize` function:

```
function sanitize(&$item, $key) {
    $item = htmlspecialchars(trim($item), ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: Great answer which allowed me to understand the issue. I ended up using `array_map` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use references.

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST,  function(&$v) {
        $v = sanitize($v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution I used (thanks to aldrin27's comment):

```
$_POST = array_map('sanitize', $_POST);
```

Comment: It won't do it recursively.